# Customize CloudKit JS container title when logging in

Tags: javascript, objective-c, cocoa, cloudkit

As seen here:
[image]

I want to customize my CloudKit JS login page with my [container name] and some image instead of showing the default "Sign in to [container ID]". How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The login page is provided by Apple, the [container name] is your app's name, and the image is actually your app icon. You can change them by changing the name and app icon of your app.
This is reasonable, as you wants the users to input their Apple ID and password. Users trust Apple more than the developer.